# How to write unit test for this controller method?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, testing

I trying to learn grails unit testing, I having a method like

```
def getProductList(){
    List<Product> products = productService.getSodaProductList();
    render(view:"productList",model:[products:products])
}
```

I want to write test function to this using GrailsUnitTestCase

I tried like this

```
void testGetSodaProductList(){
        def sodaProduct = new SodaProduct(productName:"Test Product",productDesc: "",price:10.0);
        mockDomain(SodaProduct,[sodaProduct])
        def controller = new SodaProductController();
        mockController(controller)
        def list = controller.getSodaProductList();
        assertEquals(2,list.model.products.size())
    }
```

But not working, can some suggest how to write this test function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use the following way for unit testing

**Using spock:**

```
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(SodaProductController)
@Mock([SodaProduct, ProductService])
class SodaProductControllerSpec extends Specification {

  void testGetSodaProductList() {
    when:
    SodaProduct sodaProduct = 
           new SodaProduct(productName: "Test Product", 
                           productDesc: "Desc", price: 10.0)
    controller.getProductList()

    then:
    view == "/sodaProduct/productList"
    model.products.size() == 2
  }
}
```

**Without spock:**

```
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

@TestFor(SodaProductController)
@Mock([SodaProduct, ProductService])
class SodaProductControllerTests {

  void testGetSodaProductList() {
    SodaProduct sodaProduct = 
          new SodaProduct(productName: "Test Product", 
                          productDesc: "Desc", price: 10.0)

    controller.getProductList()

    assert view == "/sodaProduct/productList"
    assert model.products.size() == 2
  }
}
```

Comment: for specification we need to install some plugins right

Comment: whats your grails version?

Comment: mine is 2.0.3, is that an issue

Comment: I am using grails 2.3.5 and it include spock. I think spock is included in 2.3.x. So yes, you need to install http://grails.org/plugin/spock plugin.

Comment: after plugin installation it is giving "java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods" exception

Comment: No such method exception getProductList() is applicable for argument types: () values: [

Comment: OK Let me try with grails 2.x

Comment: I have tried with grails 2.0.0 and it is working. I have also tested without spock. Have a look..,.

Comment: Without spock there will be no given, when, then blocks. :)